# Trivial homology groups for p-torsion groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, homology

Let $G$ be a group where each element has a $p$-power order.
Let $M$ be a $G$-module without $p$-torsion.
Here $G$ is a discrete infinite subgroup of a complete group. Then, it cannot be assumed pro-finite.
Also $M$ cannot be assumed finite.

My question is: It is true that, for any $i>1$, we have $H_i(G,M)=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ ?

Is the property true if we assume that $G$ acts trivially?

Thanks and Besties :)

Comment: I fixed some English errors (non-finite -> infinite, can not -> cannot), I'm not sure why you reverted them.

Comment: This is not true even for finite p-groups, e.g. let $G$ be cyclic of order p and $M=\mathbb{Z}$. Futher, I think you mixed $H_1$ and $H^1$.

Comment: @tj_ that's true, so OP specifically excluded these cases.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, but I would expect the OP to explain why it isn't possible to construct a counterexample from finite groups. In particular, $H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})=G_\text{ab}$. Why should it follow from the spec given by the OP that $G$ is perfect?

Comment: $H_n(\mathbb Z/p; \mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z/p$ for odd $n$. You excluded finite groups, but just take an infinite product. Perhaps you mean to assume not just that $M$ does not contain $p$-torsion, but that the action of $p$ on $M$ is invertible?